# Implement From trait on string slice and borrowed string

Tags: rust

In Rust, it's common practice to have functions which prefer string slices, `&str`, to borrowed strings, `&String`, because the `String` type implements `Deref<Target = str>`.

I am wondering if there is an idiomatic way to implement the `From<&str>` trait for a struct such that the struct can be created from either a string slice or a borrowed string. The best example I can come up with is below:

```
pub struct Base64 {
    bytes: Vec<u8>
}

impl From<&str> for Base64 {
    fn from(s: &str) -> Self {
        Base64 { bytes: base64::decode(s).unwrap() }
    }
}

impl From<&String> for Base64 {
    fn from(s: &String) -> Self {
        Base64::from(s as &str)
    }
}
```

Without the last function usage like `Base64::from(&String::from("..."))` generates the following error:

```
the trait bound `Base64: From<&String>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
  <Base64 as From<&str>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's indeed a way to make this more concise:

```rust
impl<T: Deref<Target=str>> From<&T> for Base64 {
    fn from(s: &T) -> Self {
        let s = s as &str;
        Base64 { bytes: base64::decode(s).unwrap() }
    }
}
```

and get rid of the other two trait impls. This one uses generics with trait bounds: Now *anything* that can be dereferenced to a `str` can be used with your struct.

EDIT: Alternatively, keep the non-generic version for `&str`, ditch the `String` version, and then instead call it like so:

```rust
Base64::from(String::from("...").as_ref())
```

which will alleviate the concern pointed out by @kmdreko

Comment: Its not really idiomatic though, since you're locking yourself out from implementing something like `From<&SomeExternalType>` because of trait coherence. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=36fe8749c32d8691961565e3d58da256) The standard library does them separately; see [`From<_> for String` implementations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-From%3C%26String%3E-for-String)

Comment: Good point. Maybe the more idiomatic way is to only keep `&str` implementation around and let the caller take care of the ref conversion.

Comment: That's a really good callout @kmdreko. Thanks!